# In ways (that/which/in which) you can't imagine

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-adverbs

Here's a quote from Doctor Strange (movie).

> You're a man looking at the world through a keyhole. You've spent your whole life trying to widen that keyhole to see more. to know more. And now on hearing that it can be widened **in ways you can't imagine**, you reject the possibility.

Can the boldfaced phrase be re-written as follows, without changing the original meaning in context?

> (1) in ways **that** you can't imagine
>
> (2) in ways **which** you can't imagine
>
> (3) in ways **in which** you can't imagine

Answer (score 1):

No, only the first example is grammatically correct.

> (2) in ways which you can't imagine

The relative clause used with *which* (as well as all other wh-words) always needs to be separated from the main clause by a comma, and is a non-defining relative clause. That means, the clause can be omitted without sabotaging the meaning of the sentence.

> (3) in ways in which you can't imagine

This is rather wrong in sentence meaning but I would say it's grammatically incorrect as well. As explained by @JK2 in the comment section, the *which* here replaces *ways* and is the subject taken action (*imagine*) directly upon. Therefore, it's *you can't imagine the ways*, not *you can't imagine in the ways*.

> (1) in ways that you can't imagine

Only this sentence is fully correct, as it uses *that* for a defining relative clause, which doesn't require any comma before the clause starts.

Comment: Though native speakers often get this wrong in conversation, we also get a lot of other things wrong. Thanks Gerry for reminding us all! Some sources confirming Gerry's answer: http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/which-vs-that  https://blog.prepscholar.com/relative-pronouns-on-sat-writing-which-vs-that-and-more

Answer (score -1):

Yes, all three are acceptable, though the third may not be considered good style because of the repeat preposition *in*.

Another possible expression is, "in more ways than you can imagine," similar to this famous quote from "Star Wars":

> [Strike me down and I will become more powerful than you could possibly imagine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5tpzT2mFps)

This expression is very dramatic and not often used in ordinary conversation.  You wouldn't normally say (without irony) something like:

> The soup at the college cafeteria is more delicious than you can imagine.

Comment: I wonder if (3) is simply bad style or is ungrammatical in context, the reason being, I thought in the original phrase that "ways" was the antecedent of the relative clause "you can't imagine", and that "ways" was functioning as the object of the verb "imagine" within the relative clause. If that's the case, inserting "in which" as in (3) simply doesn't work grammatically or at the very least is different from the original phrase in meaning as well as in syntax.

Comment: @JK2  It's just generally poor style to repeat the same preposition twice in the same sentence -- but native English speakers do this all the time, so it's not critical.  In this particular context "you can't imagine" directly modifies "ways" so any of the terms "that", "which" or "in which" are more or less superfluous and don't change the meaning.

Comment: @JK2 In addition to being too many "in"s too close together, I think (3) is ungrammatical. "It was the way in which she did it..." is a perfectly grammatical phrase, and often used to emphasise "the way" over the action that was performed ("It wasn't just that she did it; I was the way in which she did it that was so impressive to us."). But that "in which" can't be substituted for only "which" (*"It was the way which she did it" doesn't work). "In which" seems to be a different beast from the relative pronouns "that" and "which".